# Processing Orders in Rails 4 - Model code and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, orders

I'm having difficulty approaching a common issue of processing orders in Rails 4. I have a model object "Offers" which are then accepted by Users. This action "accept" needs to create a new Order object which saves the same attributes as the Offer object. From what I've read my code should look as follows:

```
class User
  has_many :offers
  has_many :orders, through :offers
  # ...
end

class Offer
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_one: order
  # ...
end

class Order
  belongs_to :offer

  def add_fields_from_offer(order)
    order.offer.each do |offer|
      offer_id = nil
      order << offer
    end
  end      
end
```

I would appreciate any advice on this code or the structure of this approach. The Offer object is really the transactional product so it should be destroyed once accepted. But I would like the order saved as an object for the User's account history.

This essentially means repeating the same fields but in a different model - is this a good approach or is there a better way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research I found it was easier to only use a single model (here "offers") and use the state_machine gem for assistance. This is ideal if your product goes through several stages e.g. accepted, posted, etc etc.

The documentation explains how to implement this in the model e.g.

```
state_machine :initial => :new do
          event :accept do
    transition :from => :new, :to => :accepted, :unless => :expired?
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ditch the `Offer` model entirely and add a boolean `accepted` or `is_offer` field to your `Order`.

Comment: I had considered that but what is a good way of keeping record of the transactions once they are completed? Is it better to add a condition to the index so that they no longer show to other users? I know this is fairly conceptual but the guides I have looked at suggest using an Order model for processing transactions.  Thanks

Comment: @user2514224 If you mean showing only orders and not offers, you can filter out all orders which haven't been accepted `user.orders.where(is_offer: false)`.

If you are concerned that offers are not orders and thus require a separate model to keep everything in its place, think of an offer as of an order which has not yet been finished. Like a contract not signed but still a contract.

Comment: I mean I have an index which lists all offers so the function would be to filter offers which have been accepted by other users so they don't show. Same code I assume - would I put this in the model or controller ?

Comment: You can use a named scope in the `Order` model: `scope :offers, -> { where(accepted: false) }`. Then in the controller: `@offers = Order.offers`. See [Rails Guides on Scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Comment: Ok thanks that's helpful. Can you comment on the collection method '<<'? I don't quite understand the method. How does it store the collected attributes?

Comment: @user2514224 Well, if I am correct, the code you posted doesn't make much sense and most likely won't even work. One uses `<<` when wants to add more children to a `has_many` relationship. Like, `user.orders << order`. This is equal to `order.user_id = user.id`.